# using radix sort on 32bit numbers

Tags: java, radix-sort

i was wondering, when i have a list of integers and i need to sort them,
and i know that they are integers in 32 bit, can i use radix sort (with counting sort as its stable sort) to sort them in o(n) time?

isn't it just 32 counting sorts using the bits representation on the numbers starting from LSB?

i know that general sorts with no previous knowledge of the numbers take o(nlogn), but isnt the fact that they are 32 bit integers is all i need to make it an o(n) sort?

thanks!

Comment: You can, but your memory usage might get quite large. Benchmark. For small n, this would be slower than a nlogn search due to overhead. The point where it becomes better (if it ever does) is yours to find, and will depend on the relative speed of various bits of your target machine.

Comment: You can use [Least significant digit radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts), it takes `o(nk)` time .

Comment: Radix sort is only `O(n)` in the sense that you can (sometimes) replace the `log(n)` component with the constant `log(maxN)`.

Comment: If you don't need to know how many of each there was i.e. a sorted set, you could use a couple of BitSets.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Radix sort will work fine for unsigned integers, and (with a little bit more work) for signed integers as well.

Interestingly, it will also work for non-NaN, nonnegative floating point numbers if their bits are reinterpreted as integers. (Negative floating point numbers require somewhat more work, and probably aren't worth it.)

Comment: This is Java, where did you find "unsigned" integers?

Comment: In generalized computer science. Teach a man to fish, and all that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - They have no RSA signature, hence "unsigned".

Comment: radix sort will work fine, but will it work in o(n) time?
i mean, you can say that i takes log(n) bit to represent an integer in the range of 0-n, but with these assumptions, knowing that i work on a 32 bit integer system, can i say for sure that radix sort is o(n)?

Comment: @HotLicks Excellent! What is the natural ordering of RSA signed "integers"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Only the NSA knows!

Comment: @Guy Yes. With the number of possible integers fixed as a constant, radix sort is O(n). (Incidentally, notice capital O; "little-o" is something different, and almost certainly not what you mean.)